# Query for Multiple Users - Best Practices

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have about 10 users that use their own personalized query for an internal process at my workplace.  The user inputs a few values at the top of the query, hits execute, and voila, their report shows up in the grid.  The source data tables they access are the same, but the created tables within are personalized with the suffix _User1, _User2...User10.  Each time they run the query, the previously created tables are dropped and created again.  The entire query takes about 1 second to run.

The majority of the structure looks like this repeated 5 times for the 5 steps to get to their desired output:

```
DROP TABLE z
SELECT *
INTO z
FROM y
```

Now, the number of users is multiplying to 50, and that means that each tweak in the master query code will result in me changing 50 user-specific queries and sending them back out.  Managable and annoying with 10 users, completely unmanagable with 50.

My question is, what is the best way to go about structuring the database/query?  Ideally I'd like to just have one query, one set of created tables (not 50).  Since it only takes 1 second to run, would we run the risk of two or more users (with different inputs) running the query simultaneously, accessing the same tables and somehow getting bad data because they ran it at the exact same time?

Is there a specfic way this is normally done?  Hoping someone can shed some light.

Thanks

Comment: What client are they using to run these queries?

Comment: @DanBracuk They're using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: If you're talking about all your users doing these queries in SSMS, I would *really* suggest you get a front-end developed ASAP.  Even a simple MS Access front-end would be better than giving 50 users keys to the kingdom with the possibility of doing something really stupid (like dropping a core table or database) - trust me, it happens.  It has happened at our office even when a high-profile user (our CFO) had direct access to the database and ran the wrong SQL.  It's not hard to build a simple input form where users enter the numbers and press a button to see the result in a tabular format.

Comment: Do you have access to any front-end technology you can deploy out to these users, such as a .Net app or an MS Access database?  Are all these users on the same network, or have access to some central shared folder where you could deploy app updates?  We do this kind of thing all the time, so I could walk you through how you might implement a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: As I've indicated in my comments, giving a bunch of users access directly to SSMS to run reports is a **very bad idea**.  Get some sort of front-end, even a simple MS Access database - you would only need a single license to develop the database, and you could give the rest of the users Access Runtime, for instance.  There are so many ways a user could really mess you up if they don't know what they're doing.  I will offer some ideas below, but I **don't recommend doing this**.

---

One solution: use temp tables so you don't have to worry about each user's tables overlapping:

```
-- drop the table if it already exists
if object_id('tempdb..#z') is not null
    DROP TABLE #z

SELECT *
INTO #z
FROM y
```

When you prefix a table name with `#`, it becomes a connection-scoped temporary table, which means separate sessions will not see the temporary tables in other sessions even if they have the same name.

---

Often it is not necessary to create a temp table unless you have some really complicated scenario.  You should be able to make use of subqueries, views, CTE's, and stored procedures to generate the output real-time without any new tables being involved.  You can even build views and procedures that reference other views so you can organize your complicated logic.  For example, you might encapsulate the logic into a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TheReport
(
    @ReportID int,
    @Name varchar(50),
    @SomeField varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- do some complicated query here
    SELECT field1, field2 FROM Result Q
END
```

Then you don't even have to send updates to your users (unless the fields change).  Just have their query call the stored procedure, and you can update the procedure directly at your convenience:

```
DECLARE @ReportID int
DECLARE @Name varchar(50)
DECLARE @SomeField varchar(10)

-- YOU CAN MODIFY THIS --
SET @ReportID = 5
SET @Name = 'MyName'
SET @SomeField = 'abc'
-- DON'T MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE --

EXEC [TheReport] @ReportID, @Name, @SomeField;
```

Comment: This is great stuff. As you're aware, I'm new at this. Based on your post, I stuffed away the code in an stored proc. I agree with your concerns about giving the users the keys to the kingdom which is part of the reason I figured there was a better way than this. MS Access is a thought down the road, but for now I'm a bit more comfortable with how SPs work. I know very little about CTE's, but as they say...everything in time. I'm sure I'll eventually look back at these posts and laugh, but for now I appreciate the help and knowledge. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshD: Note that stored procedures were for solving the problem of maintaining a large script for all your users.  It *doesn't* solve the problem of race conditions.  For instance, if you simply moved your query into a stored procedure, but it still creates and drops a table in the database, there is a chance two users will run it at almost the exact same time and get a weird error because the table is missing.  You still need to use either temp tables or avoid creating/dropping tables altogether.  Just want to double-check we're on the same page :)

Comment: Yes sorry, we are on the same page!  The query was updated with a # before each of the old user-created tables in order to use the tempdb.  So instead of z_User1 it's now #z.  Sorry I should have included that in my response.  Same page now? :)